# nested if in javascript for validation purpose?

Tags: javascript

I have the form values stored in javascript variables now i tried to validate in javascript

I want to know is this the right format which i'm trying to implement

```
function validate()
{
  //getting values from the form in a variable
  <!--now validation starts-->

  if(condition1==true)
  {
    if(condition2==true)
    {
      if(condition3==true)
      {
        statement1;
      }
      else
      {
        statement2;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      statement3;
    }
  }         
  else
  {
    statement4;
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't right to write in code at all! It's called a dummy code.

Comment: If that's what you want to do, then that's fine, what's your question? By the way, no need to do `if (condition==true)`; just `if (condition)` does the same thing.

Comment: will it work toraz...

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
if (!condition1) {
    statement4;
} else if (!condition2) {
    statement3;
} else if (!condition3) {
    statement2;
} else {
    statement1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to validate forms, you do not need to have nested if.

```
function validate(){

  if(b=="" || b==null){
      alert("Please enter your city");
      return false;
  }

  if(a=="" || a==null){
      alert("Please enter your address");
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```